# R syntactic sugar - Vector Distance

Tags: r, vector, distance, syntactic-sugar

I'm new to R lang, and I think there may be a simpler way to get the closest vector within a target vector.

```
# Toy data
mydata = matrix(rpois(100, lambda=10), 10, 10)
candidate = rpois(10, lambda=10)

# Append a new row and calculate Euclidean distance
dist.to.proto = dist(rbind(mydata, candidate))
# Get the latest row
x = tail(as.matrix(dist.to.proto,), 1)
# From all the distances get the minimum, exclude the distance with itself.
proto = which.min(x[x > 0])

closest.vector = mydata[proto,]
```

Comment: You could avoid calculating all pair-wise distances: `sqrt(rowSums(t(t(mydata) - candidate) ^ 2))`

Comment: The `distance()` function in my **analogue** package will do this for you, with the computations done in C so it should be reasonably speedy for even biggish problems. It is designed for comparing a matrix of candidates to a matrix of data but a single candidate will do too.

Answer (score 0):

> You could avoid calculating all pair-wise distances:
>
> sqrt(rowSums(t(t(mydata) - candidate) ^ 2))